# What is the Difference Between a Mood and Tone?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literary-device, tone, mood

The two literary devices "mood" and "tone" seem to be the same no matter where I read about them. I cannot seem to differ them.

Example: *"the dark and gloomy night"*

The sentence above is setting a worried tone while the mood is scary. But what is the difference? It basically means the same thing. I cannot seem to differ between the two literary devices.

Comment: A writer uses a certain tone (style of writing) to create a mood (feeling in the reader). I could use an ironic tone to keep you entertained while I set a dark mood about serious consequences.

Comment: @Yosef What if the readership is just two people, and one is manic? How does 'the mood generated' apply? I take it you mean 'mood typically brought about'. _But isn't 'mood' usually associated more with the work than with the (not always malleable) mood of any given (or even the average) reader_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think "mood" is the feeling the writer *intends* to evoke; whether any particular reader feels it is an individual matter.